# Solve for unknown

Tags: trigonometry

Hello Math stackexchange users!

This is my first question on math stackexchange. So if you have feedback for the question would be nice.

I am trying to solve the following

$$-\frac{M_A}{F}  k \tan⁡\left(\frac{k(L_A+2L_B )}{2}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{L_B}{r}\right) $$

$$L_B =\ ?$$

Where all other variables are real and positive.

Is it possible to solve this analytically?

Comment: You could use numerical methods, idk if you can solve this analytically

Comment: Thanks for thinking about the problem. I already solved it with a numerical method but i wanted to try to find an expression for $L_B$ or find out that it is not possible analytically.

Comment: I defined my question in a better way